# Trouble with "Delete" function in doubly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

So I've been trying to create a function that deletes a node from a doubly linked list after another node, but I keep getting a seg fault error.

Here's what I've gotten so far:

```
void _delete2(struct Node * curr, struct Node * pred)  
 {   //takes the Node to delete and the Node before it
     struct Node * temp = curr->next;
     if(curr->next == NULL)
     {
         return;
     }
     else if(temp->next->next == NULL)
     {
         curr->next = NULL;
     }
     else
     {  //this is the part that I'm having trouble with
         temp = curr->next;
         curr->next = temp->next;
         temp->next->prev = pred;
         free(temp);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a  [mcve] and read this: [ask]

Comment: BTW: a piece of paper and a pencil are most helpful for resoloving this kind of problems.

Comment: BTW: why do you need two parameters (`curr` and `pred`)? One paremeter is enough, that is the node you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code at all and I have written it off top of my head, but I think it will work. This code should delete `curr` node from doubly linked list:

```
void _delete2(struct Node * curr)  
{   
     if(curr->next == NULL)
     {
         curr->prev->next = NULL; // <-- there is no node after current one,
                            //     so node after previous one will be null
     }
     else
     {
         curr->prev->next = curr->next; // Node after before current one is the
                                        // node after current one
         curr->next->prev = curr->prev; // Node before next node will be 
                                        // node before current node after deleting.
     }
     free(curr);
}
```

In addition, I assumed that `curr` are not `NULL` which is not an illogical assumption.

**Update:**
it seems that I read question incorrectly and you want to delete node **after** current one. You can use previous method with a small check:

```
void _delete_after(struct Node * curr)  
{
    struct Node *tmp = curr->next;
    if (tmp != NULL)
        _delete2(tmp);
}
```